# Sending name/value pairs using HttpOpenRequest and HttpSendRequest

Tags: c++, winapi, httpwebrequest

I am using HttpOpenRequest to send data of the form /path?data=xyzzy. However xyzzy can be very large, 100s of k at times, and on certain machines HttpOpenRequest fails with error 122 (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)

According to [Microsoft kb 208427](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427) the Maximum URL length is 2,083 characters in Internet Explorer

but it also states

*'However, the POST method is not limited by the size of the URL for submitting name/value pairs. These pairs are transferred in the header and not in the URL'*

An answer to my question, [Why might HttpOpenRequest fail with error 122](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362983/why-might-httpopenrequest-fail-with-error-122/),
and several other sources, suggest that the data should be sent by HttpSendRequest, but this does not send the data as part of the headers, and is not being picked up as a name/value pair.

How can I send large amounts of data over http using name/value pairs?

My code is

```
std::string fURL = "/path";
std::string payload = "xml=xmldata";

HINTERNET fSessionHandle = InternetOpenW(L"Agent", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
HINTERNET fConnectHandle = InternetConnectW(fSessionHandle, L"172.24.5.42", 8090, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, WININET_API_FLAG_SYNC, 0);
HINTERNET fRequestHandle;

LPCSTR types[] = { "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", NULL };

fRequestHandle = HttpOpenRequestA(fConnectHandle, "POST", fURL.c_str(), NULL, NULL, types , INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD|INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE, 0); 

if (fRequestHandle)
{
    if (!HttpSendRequestW(fRequestHandle, NULL, -1, (LPVOID)payload.c_str(), (DWORD)payload.length()))
        std::cerr << "HTTP Send Request failed, sys error " << GetLastError();
}
else
    std::cerr << "HTTP Open Request failed, sys error " << GetLastError();
```

Comment: What exactly is not working for you?  The first set of parameters to HttpSendRequest is the headers and the second is the body; you are passing your payload as the body.  I think this is the usual method of operation for large payloads.

Comment: The target is expecting the data in the form /path?data=xyzzy, but large values of xyzzy seem to be hitting the ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER. I'm looking for a way round this before trying to change the target

Comment: You mean in the request URI?  e.g. "GET /path?data=xyzzy HTTP/1.1\r\n" on the wire?  This is just not possible with large data, at least not using WinINet.  ntcolonel's answer in your other question is the way to go.  Since the data will be sent in the body and not the headers you will have to change the target.

Comment: @Luke Do you have a reference for that? I may need some ammunition. It works on some PC's but not others

Comment: A reference for what?  WinINet has a maximum URL length of ~2080 characters; there is no getting around that hard limit.  If you want to include more data than that, you will have to POST it as the body of the HTTP request.  I guess you could add it as a HTTP header instead, but there is probably a length limit to that as well.

Comment: @Luke Our url is short, the data is sent as a name value pair, and Microsoft kb 208427 states there is no limit to name value pairs.

Comment: I think KB 208427 might be confusing the issue; that documentation specifically states that it applies to Internet Explorer.  IE may have different behavior than WinINet.  The part about sending name value pairs in the header sounds particularly odd to me.  I don't believe WinINet does any kind of special handling like that; I think it is up to the application to do those kinds of things.

Answer (score 0):

As @Luke says the answer is to put the data in the body, using the code detailed in [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362983/why-might-httpopenrequest-fail-with-error-122/)