# How to send data to a PHP page without using browsers?

Tags: php, curl, mql4

My other two questions didn't go down too well ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942048/how-do-i-post-a-long-string-into-a-php-page) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20978966/php-url-is-this-a-viable-hack)), due to my confusion and noob-ness; I'll have a final bash to clarify my problem.

I need to send historical trades and signals from my trading terminal. The code is in MQL (C variant) and uses the *Wininet.dll*. I can send data to my server using this:

```
string sData, url;
sData = "abc123,etc,etc";
url = "webname.com/PHP/insert.php?testdata="+sData;
int request = InternetOpenUrl (open, url, NULL, 0, 0, 0);
```

I want to use the *insert.php* script on my site to read the string that comes after [testdata=] and then insert it into my database for further analysis. This string could be thousands of characters long, which causes concern for URL length limitation.

People have mentioned cURL and jQuery but I don't understand how the above code can be used to simulate a POST request as the data string can get very large depending on the dates I select from my trade journal.

I want to try to do it the correct way but it's just machines talking to each other without any forms, so that's what's confusing me.

If I use [this cURL example](http://bavotasan.com/2011/post-url-using-curl-php/), how do I pass a long string to the $data variable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can simulate a POST with curl.

Comment: don't think of it as a "browser" - think in terms of HTTP requests. That's all browsers are doing when you click a link... so figure out how to generate an http request from your app and point it at your server. No browser necessary.

Comment: @GordonM - but how do i pass a long string when i'm only using url's as shown in my code snippet?

Comment: @Marc B - i can't get my head around it and i feel foolish for asking the same question thrice in different ways. I'm stuck at the first hurdle of parsing the long string to the php / cURL script as url's are limited in size.

Comment: You can write a simple program that will send the data as json then unmarshal it in your php. Must you use MQL?

Comment: you said "from my trading terminal", so your trading terminal code would be the "client", and use an http request to send data to your PHP script on the server. you'd only use curl (a server-side library) if you wanted send stuff from PHP to your terminal.

Comment: A quick google on MQL4 (never personally used it) reveals something like [this](http://codebase.mql4.com/4428) which I think should suit you?

Comment: "If [I] use this cURL example, how do [I] pass a long string to the $data variable?" - as long as you like, since it is POST. As per the comments on your previous questions(s), the limit with your current GET approach is the maximum length of the URL/query string, which is around 2,000 characters.

Comment: @Scopey - txs for the link, i'm a bit suspicious of personal dll's in my terminal, but the example in the comments shows a nice javascript thingy to extrapolate the fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success :)))))))))))))

I've managed to write to my database with tens of thousands of characters. I had problems connecting because I was using http:// in the domain name, but when i removed it the code worked and I was able to talk to my script.

**MQL (C language)**

```
string myData = "testdata=abc123etc...";
string header = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
int open = InternetOpen("HTTP_Client_Sample", 0, "", "", 0); 
int connect = InternetConnect(open, "website.com", 80, "", "", 3, 0, 1); 
int request = HttpOpenRequest(connect, "POST", "/PHP/insert.php", NULL, NULL, acceptTypes, 0, 1);
HttpSendRequest(request, header, StringLen(header), myData , StringLen(myData));
```

**PHP**

Notice how i'm now able to use $_POST method which has a limitation of:

suhosin.post.max_value_length 1000000

More than enough for my needs. Before, my PHP script used $_GET which can only read 512 chars.

```
include("connect.php"); //Connect to the database
$data = $_POST['testdata'];
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (testdata) VALUES ('$data')");
if ($result) echo $data;
else echo "Error ".$mysqli->error;
mysql_close();
```

Thank you for everyone's help, it's greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wininet's [`HttpSendRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to accomplish the POST while keeping the URL short with as little GET/query data as possible. You'll also be using [`HttpOpenRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Some sample c++ code is available from [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362983/why-might-httpopenrequest-fail-with-error-122/) stackoverflow post. You can change the `dataPayload` to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the info - i read a few MQL codebase threads about HttpOpenRequest and the comments showed users failing when they used POST instead of GET, so i started chasing my own tail it seems looking for an easier way of just creating a URL and using InternetOpenUrlA, but it seems this is flawed from the get-go as POST needs header info et al. I'll research your links and most likely mark your answer as the best; thanks for your input.