# Passing Multiple params HttpPostRequest c++

Tags: c++, http

I have this function to send HTTP POST requests in C++, but i am having a little problem passing multiple strings arguments to it. Here's my code so far:

```
#include <Windows.h>
int doHttpPost(char *szDomain, char *szPage, char *szPost)
{
    int iReturn = 1;
    HINTERNET hSession = NULL;
    HINTERNET hConnect = NULL;
    HINTERNET hRequest = NULL;

    static TCHAR hdrs[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    const char *accept[2]={"*/*", NULL};
    TCHAR *frmdata = szPost;

    hSession = InternetOpen("AGENT", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    if(hSession)
    {
            hConnect = InternetConnect(hSession, szDomain, INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
            if(hConnect)
            {
                    hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, "POST", szPage, NULL, NULL, accept, INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE | INTERNET_FLAG_NO_COOKIES | INTERNET_FLAG_NO_UI | INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);
                    if(hRequest)
                    {
                            if(HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, strlen(hdrs), frmdata, strlen(frmdata)))
                                    iReturn = 0;
                            else
                                    iReturn = 5;
                    }
                    else    //HttpOpenRequest
                            iReturn = 3;
            }
            else    //InternetConnect
                    iReturn = 2;
    }
    else  //InternetOpen
            iReturn = 1;

    //Cleanup
    InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
    InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
    InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);

    return iReturn;
}
```

I call the function this way:

```
 doHttpPost((char*)"127.0.0.1",(char*)"/test/post.php",(char*)postreq);
```

Is there a way I can add multiple requests in the post field, such as:

```
 value1=id&value2=password&value3=details
```

where `id`, `password` and `details` will be variables containing data.

Comment: The code is about right, what exactly goes wrong? See also [Why might HttpOpenRequest fail with error 122?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362983/why-might-httpopenrequest-fail-with-error-122/) with a related code snippet in the answer.

Comment: the code works just fine..i just need a way to pass multiple params in the post fields(postreq) in this format  value1=id&value2=password&value3=details

Comment: That is, you found how to send fixed string, and now you want to build it from variables?

Comment: yes ..that it is exactly..i need to build it from variables

Answer (score 1):

You can build a string from parts using [`sprintf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybk95axf.aspx) and friends.

The simplest code snippet, which however ignores escaping you need to do on the values, is as follows:

```
CHAR pszRequest[1024] = { 0 };
CHAR* pszValue1 = "id";
CHAR* pszValue2 = "password";
CHAR* pszValue3 = "details";
sprintf(pszRequest, "value1=%s&value2=%s&value3=%s", 
    pszValue1, pszValue2, pszValue3);

doHttpPost((char*) "127.0.0.1", (char*) "/test/post.php", pszRequest);
```

For a robust solution you need to read up on basic string manipulation functions, and check RFC that defines body format for "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" MIME type.